# c# Out of memory exception when loading large number of images

Tags: c#, visual-studio, powerpoint

I am working on a Visual Studio c# project. I am creating a large number of buttons in a powerpoint add-in, each of which has an image created from a slide from a library of powerpoint presentations. When the number of buttons gets above 450 it always crashes with an out of memory exception.

I have researched the issue and understand that I need to dispose of something somewhere in order to free up some memory. I'm not clear on how to do this though.

This is the code I am using to create the images, each image is added to a button as it is created. It crashes on the line canvas.DrawImageUnscaled(sourceImage, 0, 0);

```
public static Image CreateNonIndexedImage(string path)
    {
        using (var sourceImage = Image.FromFile(path))
        {
            var targetImage = new Bitmap(sourceImage.Width, sourceImage.Height,
              PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
            using (var canvas = Graphics.FromImage(targetImage))
            {
                canvas.DrawImageUnscaled(sourceImage, 0, 0);
            }
            return targetImage;
        }
    }
```

Exception thrown: 'System.OutOfMemoryException' in System.Drawing.dll

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT:

Here is the code where I use CreateNonIndexedImage, the image is then resized and added to the button.

```
for (int i = 0; i < numThumbs; i++)
{
                    Image img = CreateNonIndexedImage(ThumbsPath + thumbsList[i].Name);

                    int newHeight = maxHeight;
                    int newWidth = maxWidth;

                    if (img.Width > maxWidth)
                    {
                        float ratio = (float)img.Width / maxWidth;
                        float h = img.Height / ratio;
                        newHeight = (int)h;

                        img = resizeImage(img, new Size(maxWidth, newHeight));
                    }

                    if (img.Height > maxHeight)
                    {
                        float ratio = (float)img.Height / maxHeight;
                        float w = img.Width / ratio;
                        newWidth = (int)w;

                        img = resizeImage(img, new Size(newWidth, newHeight));
                    }

                    int bW = (img.Width + 20) > minWidth ? img.Width + 20 : minWidth;

                    //CREATE BUTTON FOR SLIDE
                    Button b = new Button();
                    b.AccessibleName = thumbsList[i].Name;
                    b.Text = slideTitle;
                    b.TextAlign = ContentAlignment.BottomCenter;
                    b.Image = img;
                    b.Width = bW;
                    b.Height = img.Height + 40;
                    b.ImageAlign = ContentAlignment.TopCenter;
                    b.BackColor = Color.AliceBlue;
                    b.Click += SlideButton_Click;
                    flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(b);
}
```

EDIT:

Source code for resizeImage:

```
private static Image resizeImage(Image imgToResize, Size size)
    {
        int sourceWidth = imgToResize.Width;
        int sourceHeight = imgToResize.Height;

        float nPercent = 0;
        float nPercentW = 0;
        float nPercentH = 0;

        nPercentW = ((float)size.Width / (float)sourceWidth);
        nPercentH = ((float)size.Height / (float)sourceHeight);

        if (nPercentH < nPercentW)
            nPercent = nPercentH;
        else
            nPercent = nPercentW;

        int destWidth = (int)(sourceWidth * nPercent);
        int destHeight = (int)(sourceHeight * nPercent);

        Bitmap b = new Bitmap(destWidth, destHeight);
        Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage((Image)b);
        g.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;

        g.DrawImage(imgToResize, 0, 0, destWidth, destHeight);
        g.Dispose();

        return (Image)b;
    }
```

Comment: The `Bitmap` object is also `IDisposable`. Are you disposing of those too?

Comment: Why you create two identical images? Use only one.

Comment: Alexander, I don't create two identical images, all the images are different.

Comment: Enigmativity, can I dispose of the Bitmap object even though I am returning it?

Comment: @kwibbler You need to give more context, how you're using your CreateNonIndexedImage function. How big are these buttons? It sounds like they're quite small, but the source images are larger. So the answer is probably to Draw-Scaled. But also, how many buttons do you actually show on the screen at a time? If they're not currently viewed on the screen, don't create the objects yet. The returned Image needs to eventually be disposed, but if they're being displayed, they'll need to remain. (And no, don't dispose it before you return)

Comment: @kwibbler - No, you can't. You have to dispose of it when you finish with it. If you don't you might find yourself running out of memory. It depends how many you create.

Comment: @Todd I've edited the post, it now shows the code I use to add the images to the buttons. The buttons are in a flowlayout panel, there are probably no more than 10 visible at a time at the moment, depending on the screensize, the rest are off screen, you can scroll down to show them.

Comment: Please give source code for `resizeImage`.

Comment: First and foremost, you must control memory properly, use Dispose and explicitly call `GC.Collect` at regular intervals.  Second, do you have the luxury of supporting only 64-bit of PowerPoint (thus never supporting 32-bit version of PP)?  If so, then make your plugin 64-bit only.  Third, can your final result bitmaps be at a reduced bitdepth, to help save memory?  Do they really need to be 4 bytes / pixel?

Comment: @apocalypse source code added

Comment: @ChrisO Thank you for your comments. I am not sure exactly what I should be calling Dispose on. Adding GC.Collect after   flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(b) had no effect, is that the correct place to do so? Please excuse my ignorance here. I have reduced the bitdepth and for the time being this has fixed the issue, however it may of course come back if more images are required. Regarding the 64-bit question, I need to ask the client.

Comment: You shouldn't need to call GC.Collect. When memory gets too high, it will automatically collect. You only get an out of memory exception, when GC can't collect because resources remain undisposed.

Comment: @Todd It depends, if you are allocating many bitmaps "too quickly" it may be necessary to call `GC.Collect` yourself, but one must call `Dispose` properly in the first place though.

Comment: Nah, if you have disposed it, and memory runs out, GC will collect to make more room. There are rarely times you need to manually call collect.

Comment: @Todd You should try writing an interesting image processing app, I assure you it will be most instructive.

Comment: My suggestions come from experience and a deep understanding of the inner workings of .net, mono, managed memory and generational gc

Answer (score 2):

you create three instance of each image in

- CreateNonIndexedImage
- resizeImage (in if (img.Width > maxWidth))
- resizeImage (in if (img.Height > maxHeight))

you may dispose the old image after resizing and then set the new instance to the img variable as below

```
var newImg = resizeImage(img, new Size(maxWidth, newHeight));
img.Dispose();
img = newImg;
```

Comment: Thank you! This solution and the one above helped solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was inside resizeImage.

1. Dispose the img parameter inside the resizeImage funtion before returning
2. I'm not sure, but if this is a XAML/WPF environment, you should save the final image back to disk, and give your button the file reference, then WPF will only load images showing into memory. (You should load and save the resized images only if the resized version doesn't exist yet.)
3. Also, you should only need one draw operation, you currently have 3 - that's will save CPU, [1] will fix the memory problem. You should be able to figure that out.

Updated code:

```
private static Image resizeImage(Image imgToResize, Size size)
{
    int sourceWidth = imgToResize.Width;
    int sourceHeight = imgToResize.Height;

    float nPercent = 0;
    float nPercentW = 0;
    float nPercentH = 0;

    nPercentW = ((float)size.Width / (float)sourceWidth);
    nPercentH = ((float)size.Height / (float)sourceHeight);

    if (nPercentH < nPercentW)
        nPercent = nPercentH;
    else
        nPercent = nPercentW;

    int destWidth = (int)(sourceWidth * nPercent);
    int destHeight = (int)(sourceHeight * nPercent);

    Bitmap b = new Bitmap(destWidth, destHeight);
    Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage((Image)b);
    g.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;

    g.DrawImage(imgToResize, 0, 0, destWidth, destHeight);
    g.Dispose();

    imgToResize.Dispose(); //IMPORTANT CHANGE HERE

    return (Image)b;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this solution (and the one below) helped solve the problem.